Smartsheet API Invalid Access Token Exception
I am trying to run the a simple Smartsheet API test program to list sheets using the Smartsheet API SDK for java.  Below is my code.  I am copying and pasting my token after creating a token from my Smartsheet account.  I am always getting the following error:  Thanks in advance for any help.
java -ea -jar build/jar/test_applications/Test.jar 
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
com.smartsheet.api.AuthorizationException: Your Access Token is invalid.
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.smartsheet.api.internal.AbstractResources$ErrorCode.getException(AbstractResources.java:148)
    at com.smartsheet.api.internal.AbstractResources.handleError(AbstractResources.java:895)
    at com.smartsheet.api.internal.AbstractResources.listResourcesWithWrapper(AbstractResources.java:503)
    at com.smartsheet.api.internal.SheetResourcesImpl.listSheets(SheetResourcesImpl.java:178)
    at Test.main(Test.java:29)


// Library includes.
import com.smartsheet.api.*;
import com.smartsheet.api.models.*;
import com.smartsheet.api.models.enums.*;
import java.util.*;

// Class definition.
public class Test
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    try
    {
      Smartsheet smartsheet = SmartsheetFactory.createDefaultClient("mytoken");
      PagedResult<Sheet> sheets = smartsheet.sheetResources().listSheets(null, null, null);
      System.out.println("\nFound " + sheets.getTotalCount() + " sheets\n");
    }
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}


This error will occur if you're using the API with a Smartsheet EU account or a Smartsheet GOV account and haven't correctly set the base URI within the SDK config file(s).
If you're using the Smartsheet API with a Smartsheet EU account or a Smartsheet GOV account, then you'll need to modify the base URI in the SDK's config file(s) to point to api.smartsheet.eu or api.smartsheetgov.com.

Base URI for Smartsheet EU: https://api.smartsheet.eu/2.0

Base URI for Smartsheet GOV: https://api.smartsheetgov.com/2.0


In the API docs, this is mentioned here:

Smartsheet EU: https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/#section/Smartsheet-Regions-Europe

Smartsheet GOV: https://smartsheet.redoc.ly/#section/Smartsheet-Gov


There are instructions specific to each SDK on how to modify the base URI in the config file(s). For the Smartsheet Java SDK, this information can be found here:

Using the API with Smartsheet EU accounts

Using the API with Smartsheet GOV accounts



Excellent!  That solved my problem as my account is indeed a Smartsheet Gov account.  I used the SmartsheetFactory.createDefaultGovAccountClient method instead of the SmartsheetFactory.createDefaultGovAccountClient method using the java SDK.  Thanks so much.

Awesome -- thanks for the update, and glad I could help!
